# Integrate $ \int \frac{x^2 + x}{(e^x + x +1)^2}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$ \int \frac{x^2 + x}{(e^x + x +1)^2}dx $$

I cant think of any substitution to start this question.

Comment: Can you think of how the quotient rule helps here?

$${\left(\frac{P}{Q}\right)}'={\frac{P'\cdot Q - P \cdot Q'}{Q^2}}$$

Comment: Try adding and subtracting $xe^x$ from the numerator.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri So you're suggesting to solve the differential equation $(P'(e^x + x + 1) - P(e^x + 1) = x^2 + x$

Comment: @user230452 I tried that way but it's not helping.

Comment: Try differentiating $x + \frac{x + 1}{e^x + x + 1} - \ln(e^x + x + 1)$. Sometimes things just fall from the sky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$I = \int\frac{x^2+x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}dx = \int\frac{e^{-2x}(x^2+x)}{(1+xe^{-x}+e^{-x})^2}dx$$

So $$I = \int\frac{[(1+xe^{-x}+e^{-x})-1](xe^{-x})}{(1+xe^{-x}+e^{-x})^2}dx$$

Now put $(1+xe^{-x}+e^{-x}) = t\;,$ Then $xe^{-x}dx = -dt$

So Integral $$I = -\int \frac{(t-1)}{t^2}dt = \int\frac{1-t}{t^2}dt$$

So we get $$I = -\frac{1}{t}-\ln|t|+\mathcal{C} = \frac{e^x}{1+x+e^{x}}-\ln \left|\frac{1+x+e^{x}}{e^x}\right|+\mathcal{C}$$

So we get $$I = x-\frac{e^x}{1+x+e^{x}}-\ln|1+x+e^{x}|+\mathcal{C}$$